# How to get the selected item of onContextItemSelected (android)?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm populating a list view using the following code:

```
for(...){
    ...
        String api = c.getString(TAG_1);
        ...
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(TAG_1, api);
        map.put(TAG_2, id_cot);
        map.put(TAG_3, ver);
        map.put(TAG_4, name);
        oslist.add(map);
    ...
}
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(CotizacionesActivity.this, oslist,
                            R.layout.list_v,
                            new String[] { TAG_1, TAG_2, TAG_3, TAG_4 },       
                            new int[] {R.id.id_cot,R.id.vers,R.id.name, R.id.api});
list.setAdapter(adapter);
registerForContextMenu(list);
```

i can't realize how to get the "R.id.id_cot" of the selected item. I do know how to get the position, but not the item

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            int index = info.position;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1 list = 1 adapter. Why are you looping it?

Comment: that´s because i insert a listadapter in a listview ?

Comment: As I said 1 ListView = 1 Adapter.. Do you mean that your ListView has other ListViews?

Comment: no, i edited the code